# Fix a point in UIView

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIView. I have a particular point in that UIView. I need to fix that point in its present position. So, when I rotate the view, that point must be in the same position. How can I do this?

```
bubbleTail = [[BubbleTail alloc] initWithFrame:bubbleTailFrame];
[self addSubview:bubbleTail];
```

Comment: Rotate the view around that point?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint

Comment: The top center of the view must be fixed so that the position of the point before rotating should be the same, even after rotating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the view's layer's `anchorPoint`. Normally, the anchor point is in the center, but if I understand you correctly, you want to change that. Note that since this is done through Core Animation, every coordinate is a value between `0.0` and `1.0`. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW17) doc for more information.

Comment: Imagine my view. The top center should be in the same position even after rotating. anchorPoint moves this. The top center should be in the same point irrespective of the rotation of the view.